# Finding out when lightning-record-form has finished rendering?

Tags: lightning-web-components, asynchronous, lwc-dom

I have a LWC which displays the Compact Layout as a popup in a graph using [lightning-record-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation). The LWC holds a `<slot>` in which the popup-lwc has the record for like so.

`<template> 
  <div class="popup>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>`

When I click on different nodes I need to re calculate the position and for that I need the height and width of the popup.

I use 
`this.template.querySelector("div.popup")`
to get the div that wraps the `<lightning-record-form>` and from that the clientWidth & clientHeight.

The clientWidth and Height are always the ones of the node clicked on before, so off by one click.

Here's an example of what the values in the div from the querySelector are:

1. Click on first node (actual width = 150, height = 200):

   ```
   width = 0 height = 0
   ```
2. Click on second node (actual width = 100, height = 75):

   ```
   width = 150 height = 200
   ```
3. Click on third node (actual = 150, height = 250):

   ```
   width = 100 height = 75
   ```

I suppose that since the `<lightning-record-form>` is rendered asynchronously I would have to wait for that to finish to get the updated and correct clientHeight/Width or could something else be the reason?

Is there a way to find out when that has finished rendering?

For example an event I could listen to so I always begin calculating with the newest sizes?

---

Edit: [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/JjwEJL2-K/4) is a link to a playground showing sample code.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. At what point are you calling `this.template.querySelector("div.popup")`? Can you show full relevant code so as to understand? Or else you can create a [playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/JjwEJL2-K/2/edit) also.

Comment: In the `renderedCallback()` of the outside LWC.

Sure, I replicated the basic idea [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/JjwEJL2-K/4). 
The crucial part is  the popup.js relocate funciton.